# Positioning text within button in Android

Tags: android, button, margin

I have a button with a symbol of an arrow. Besides, I want to have some margin between the button and the adjacent elements:

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/TSPrev"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_light"
        android:text="@string/left"
        android:textSize="60sp" />
```

However, when I do this, the arrow appears like this:

[image]

How can I keep the text centered vertically when I have margins? Without them, the button text appears correctly.

Thanks

Comment: Try android:gravity="center"

Comment: Arrow is part of background? You can also try ImageButton

Answer (score 0):

May be This will Help You :

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/notification"
    style="@style/Wrap"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    android:background="@drawable/red_shape_corner"
    android:drawableRight="@drawable/notification_bell"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:text="@string/str_notification"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
```

You Need to use

```
// Nothing but Image like Arrow etc.
android:drawableRight="@drawable/notification_bell"

// Here you can put you text
android:text="@string/str_notification"
```

Comment: So your advice is to have the arrow as an image instead of text? I couldn't understand very well your answer, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `android:gravity="center"`.

[android:gravity attribute documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3agravity)